# How can I find out who froze a (non-literal) Ruby string?

Tags: ruby

I am debugging a memory leak in a large Rails app and after looking at a heap dump I found that the cause is many frozen strings that are data and shouldn't have been frozen.

The contents of the strings make it easy to find where they were created but I don't know what code is responsible for freezing them. I could dig through and find it eventually but now I'm really curious about a way of determining who was responsible for freezing specific strings in the heap.

Monkey patching `String#freeze` did not reveal anything.

Any suggestions for figuring out where/why a freeze occurred? I don't mind patching Ruby itself and augmenting `rb_str_freeze` or `rb_obj_freeze` if I have to. I can target the problem strings by looking at the first 40 characters.

Comment: what was your monkey patch?

Comment: @JoshBrody I used alias_method_chain. `def freeze_with_debug...` `alias_method_chain :freeze, :debug`  It works for `"my-bad-string".freeze` but is never called on a problem string in the app.

Comment: Why do you think the string shouldn't be frozen? I don't think that freezing strings should increase the memory it takes up (if anything, I would expect it to go down). see https://www.wyeworks.com/blog/2015/12/01/immutable-strings-in-ruby-2-dot-3/ for more information on frozen strings

Comment: @baseballlover723 These are big chunks of HTML from inside a template (a Rails partial) that live in the heap forever. There chunk is different every time the template is rendered and so the heap grows boundlessly.   This is only happening intermittently to a piece of 1 specific page and it seems like it would be easy to track down but I can't find it. I thought it would be faster and less fuss to target it some other way since I know what the problem string will look like.

Comment: if you know where the strings are created then maybe try `created_string.singleton_class.instance_eval { undef_method(:freeze) }` and see where the crash happens?

Comment: Suppose `s = 'cat'; s.method(:freeze).super_method.call #=> "cat";  s[1]="o" #=> FrozenError (can't modify frozen String)`. `'cat'.method(:freeze).super_method #=> #<Method: Kernel#freeze>`. Is there any way `Kernel#freeze` could have been used to freeze those strings? If the possibility is even remove try monkey-patching `Kernal#freeze` as well.

Comment: Roger Rabbit did it. One possible clue is mentioned [here](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/mutable_and_immutable_objects.html): "Ruby sometimes copies objects and freezes the copies. When you use a string as a hash key, Ruby actually copies the string, freezes the copy, and uses the copy as the hash key: that way, if the original string changes later on, the hash key isn't affected."